# I uninstall anaconda and my files disappear. How can I get them back

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, anaconda, uninstallation

I download anaconda, jupyter today. I was trying to make develop envirment for data-mining by python.
But some of files were weird so I decided to uninstall anaconda and reinstall it. Than I clicked icon named "uninstall-anaconda". After uninstallation my files and download folder were gone. How can I get these back?

Comment: OK when you say your files were gone, do you mean the files that were extracted from the anaconda installer? Or are you referring to your personally created ipynb files? @user401218

Comment: @DeepakM I meant the files unrelated to anaconda or python. Of course files extracted from anaconda installer too were gone. But other files(e.g. Classical mechanics.pdf) were gone as well.